# The type must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'

Tags: c#

I create a generic class:

```
public class Pair<L, R>
{
    public L? left;
    public R? right;
    // some code
}
```

I want to use there null-able variables for generic types. Compiler gives the error:

> The type must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as
>   parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable'

What should be the correct construct in this case to overcome this error? Thank you.

Comment: do you wish to use value types only with this class or both value types and reference types?

Comment: Side note: don't use public fields, make them properties. And do read up on immutable, your Pair<> should probably be designed like that.

Comment: Of course, I use fields. Originally, they were private. I exposed publics here just to cut code and illustrate the problem as concise as possible. Solution does not depend on are they private or public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can constrain them to be value types:

```
 public class Pair<L, R>  
     where L: struct
     where R: struct
```

But that disallows reference types (classes), it's not clear if that is what you want.
When L and R are reference types you don't need the `?`

Writing a generic Pair that allows both is a lot harder. I'm not sure if it can be done directly. Maybe in C# 8.

Otherwise you'll need some wrapper around the members.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will it work also for primitive types, which are not structures? If I had limitation to complex types, I could have done just null check internally. But I want to use it universally with template types, which are not null-able as such. For instance, bool, int etc.

Comment: The correct syntax is `public class Pair<L, R> where L : struct where R: struct`, no comma after the first 'struct`. Strange but true.

Comment: @BorisZinchenko: Primitive types *are* structures.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, Thank you very much for clarification. I will try to compile and then mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HeinzKessler - yeah, had to look that up.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to achieve a generic, which can mix both primitive types and classes. I will experiment now to see, if it is possible. Anyway, I m grateful for a hint.

Comment: @BorisZinchenko: if you want to express that a value may be missing, and use both value types and reference types at will, you will have to use an option type. There are several implementations available for use with C#; please search and explore which one is suitable for your use case.

Comment: @dumetrulo, Thank you. In fact, it is an intent. I will explore according to your valuable advise.